# How to access documents which are shared with me from my docusign account through api?

Tags: docusignapi, docusignapextoolkit

How I can access document which are shared with me in my docusign account through api ?

Comment: how are they shared with you?

Answer (score 0):

Envelopes are shared, not documents.

If you know the envelope_id, you can use the [Envelopes:get](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/get/) API call.

If you want a list of the envelopes that were shared with you, then I'd try the Folders:list and Folders:listItems. See [docs](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/folders/folders/)

I'd also turn on [API logging](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging), then list the envelopes via the DocuSign web app to see how the web app uses the API to obtain the list of envelopes that were shared with you.